# Where is the documentation for iwlib.py

Tags: python, linux, wifi

This Python module exists for manipulating wireless interfaces, but there is no documentation for it anywhere.  Adding insult, the release notes repeatedly say "check the documentation".

Where is it?  Is anyone using this?  Has anyone seen it?

Answer (score 0):

It was lost in 2008 and nobody was able to find it ever since...

If you are referring to [python-iwlib](https://github.com/nathan-hoad/python-iwlib), then you can simply use auto-completion in IPython to see what functions you have access to (there aren't that many) and the corresponding docstrings. For instance,

```
In [1]: import iwlib
In [2]: iwlib.iwconfig.set_essid?
Type:        builtin_function_or_method
String form: <built-in function set_essid>
Docstring:
Set the ESSID of an interface. 

Arguments:
 - device to work on (e.g. eth1, wlan0).
 - essid to set device to.
```

Otherwise, you can check out the source code at github (it uses the Python/C API), and since it's a wrapper of the Wireless Extension library on Linux, it is safe to assume that it exposes the functions defined in this library (if you manage to find its documentation, that is).